# CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture -how to set via excel VBA

Tags: c#, excel, regional-settings, currentculture, vba

CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture -through C# we can set this value, but is it possible to set this via VBA. in an xla file..

Comment: looks difficult - have a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb157877.aspx

Comment: VBA has access to the Application.International and Application.LanguageSettings properties, but these are both read-only. Whilst you may be able to change CurrentCulture via API or externall calls from VBA I would be careful about changing CurrentCulture within an Excel session: I suspect the results would be unpredictable.